# codeigniter restful api yielding null value with status code 400 in PUT operations

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, postman

I cant be able to carry PUT operations on my codeigniter restful api app due to status code 400.

Here is the controller:

```
    public function index_put(){
// for put you need to pass id as parameter 

// Use validation library, instead of checking just for value.
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('id','ID','trim|required|integer');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // send back list of validation errors.
 $this->response(
 $this->validation_errors(),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

$update=$this->cities_model->update($this->post('id'),$this->post('city'));
if(!is_null($update))
{
    $this->response(array('response' => 'content updated 
    successfully'),REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
   }
  else
 {
 $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, technical error occurred, please 
 try again later...'), REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
}
}
```

Comment: any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that *PUT method* is not working with me. Using *POST method* instead saved my day.